# How to address a typedefed inner class of a class template that itself is a template?

Tags: c++, templates, syntax

I have a syntactic question rather,

With the following iterator class inside of a vector class,

```cpp
#include <memory>
#include <cstddef>
#include <iterator>

namespace ft { template <class T, class Alloc = std::allocator<T> > class vector; }

template <class T, class Alloc>
class   ft::vector
{
    public:
        typedef T                                           value_type;
        typedef typename allocator_type::reference          reference;
        typedef typename allocator_type::pointer            pointer;
        typedef ptrdiff_t                                   difference_type;
        template <class value_type>
        class   ptr_iterator : public std::iterator<std::random_access_iterator_tag, value_type>
        {
            public:
                ptr_iterator();
        };
        typedef ptr_iterator<value_type>                    iterator;
        typedef ptr_iterator<const value_type>              const_iterator;
};
```

How can I address the constructor of `ptr_iterator` outside of the declaration?

I tried this way:

```
template <class T, class Alloc>
ft::vector<T, Alloc>::iterator::iterator() {}
```

But it yields

```
Vector.hpp:120:1: error: specializing member 'ft::vector<T, Alloc>::ptr_iterator<T>::iterator' requires 'template<>' syntax
 ft::vector<T, Alloc>::iterator::iterator() {}
```

I attempted adding <> after both of the `iterator` words and replacing the second `iterator` word with `ptr_iterator,` but it still doesn't compile.

Can I still use the typedef without repeating both templates above the function signature?

Or is there a better design for the iterator declaration that'll allow me to define both iterator and const_iterator?

Comment: I don't think you can avoid repeating the template parameter list; you need to do something like `template <class T, class Alloc>
template <class value_type>
ft::vector<T, Alloc>::ptr_iterator<value_type>::ptr_iterator() {}`

Comment: A minor point about terminology: C++ doesn't formally have "inner" classes; it has **nested** classes. Mostly it doesn't matter, but Java's inner classes have semantics that don't exist in C++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the out-of-line definition, you must unfortunately repeat the entire "signature" of all the nested templates, including constraints, if any. Cigien has given the right form:

```
template <class T, class Alloc>
template <class value_type>
ft::vector<T, Alloc>::ptr_iterator<value_type>::ptr_iterator() 
{}
```

Since this can be messy and error-prone, you can also define the nested class inline, or alternatively as a non-nested helper class. In libstdc++, the former approach is taken for the iterators of views, but the latter for containers like `std::vector`, [for example](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/4f3b1a09d3109f03299a2ac15cfa3059596fcb1d/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/stl_vector.h#L452):

```
      typedef __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<pointer, vector> iterator;
      typedef __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const_pointer, vector>
      const_iterator;
```

##### Edit:

Oh dear, I'm not sure if it's even possible to define an operator like that! Since it's a free function, it doesn't need the nested template parameters and I would put it in the `ft` namespace. It would have to look like this:

```
namespace ft {
template <class T, class Alloc, class value_type>
bool operator==(
    typename vector<T, Alloc>::template ptr_iterator<value_type> const& lhs, 
    typename vector<T, Alloc>::template ptr_iterator<value_type> const& rhs)
{ return true; }
}
```

However, I've tried this code on [Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/jn58oPK3x) and my compiler complains that it cannot deduce the parameter(s) of the vector class.

Comment: thank you so much. I was trying to search the link given by you to see an example of how to define a relational operator for that vector's iterator and iterators in general, but couldn't find anything useful. they shouldn't be defined as members of the iterator class, right? should I post a separate question addressing this issue? my compiler too fails to deduce.

Comment: @Mampac The issue is that the argument types of the operator will be the iterator type, not the vector, even though it happens to be nested inside it. The template arguments of the iterator can be deduced, but not those of the vector. There are three ways around this: make the operator a member (which can be defined out-of-line), an inline ("hidden") friend, or else the iterator must be a separate class, in which case the operators can be regular free functions, as in libstdc++ bits/stl_iterator.h.

Comment: much obliged. i believe the best option is to go for STL's implementation and define the iterator class separately. i just wanted to ask whether there's any disadvantage of doing this (in contrast to defining inside the vector) from the OOP design point of view?